# XAML and Glyphs for buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml

What's the best way to use glyphs for buttons ?
I have an WPF app which has a lot of buttons and I wonder what's the best way to use them.
I think it's about deploying the app.
Thank's

Comment: I'm assuming your glyph is a XAML object, then best way (i think) is to define your glyph style in XAML as a resource and then create a default template for button containing glyph.

Comment: Please what do you mean by a XAML object

Comment: I mean it is defined in .xaml resource dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
    <BarButtonItem Name="buttonItem0" Content="Button Item" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/icon.png" Description="Test button item" Hint="Testing glyph on button" ItemClick="notImplemented" CommandParameter="none" />
    <BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="buttonItem0" />
```